# Unable to install Express.js

Tags: nodejs, npm

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. I was able to install Node.js using the following commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

It worked. I tried to install Express with the following command:

```
sudo npm install -g express --save
```

This gave the following output:

```
/usr/lib
`-- express@4.13.4
```

However, when I tried to test it, it did not work. I used the following commands:

```
mkdir test
cd test
express
```

This threw an error that Express was not installed.

How can I get the npm install to work?

Comment: The  node-express package is already in the default repositories. I was simply wondering why the npm install didn't work, and if the default package was up to date.

Comment: try to install it with _sudo npm install -g express --save_

Answer (score 1):

Alternative package managers generally are good at delivering up-to-date packages across multiple OS platforms, but they are generally not as good as the default system package manager at avoiding conflicts with other packages. I have the node-express package from the Ubuntu Software Center installed in Ubuntu 14.04, and it seems to be working properly when running this single file hello_world code with the command: `nodejs hello_world.js # then load http://localhost:3000/ in a web browser to see the output.`.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

The version of node-express from the default repositories in Ubuntu 14.04 is 2.5.8. The version of node-express from the default repositories in Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 is 4.1.1. The current version of expressjs from [the official Express website](https://expressjs.com/) is <s>4.13.4</s> 4.16.1. Express from the default repositories of the latest version of Ubuntu is almost as up-to-date as its latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing `express-generator`, see [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express#quick-start) for details.

To solve your issue, try

```
sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

This will install the `express` cli tool that you are trying to use (and is not installed).

Edit: Sorry about the necro, didn't see this was an old question. I'll leave the answer here anyway, maybe it'll help someone with this issue in the future.